# Placing the mdTooltip above and left

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-cli

Could anyone help me out about `mdTooltipPosition`?

Is it possible to put the `mdTooltip` above and also left?

[image]

want to place it right above the placeholder....

here is the source.

```
      <div>
    <md-input-container class="full-width">
      <input mdInput required placeholder="商品コード" [(ngModel)]="itemCd" mdTooltip="Tooltip!" mdTooltipPosition="above" />
    </md-input-container>
  </div>
```

Thank you so much.....

Comment: which CSS framework are you using?

Comment: Im using bootstrap.

Comment: share us the link of that framework.

Comment: link of framework....do you mean the HTML and CSS component....??

Comment: This is not bootstrap, it's angular-material 2 with a version < beta.10.

Comment: yeah... see the version of the framework which you are using and see the official documentation for that version. Many of the things are changed in latest Angular material version

Comment: oh sorry for my misunderstanding...yes it is angular-material 2 with a version < beta.10.

Comment: couldn't find the official documentation for above version. so I read this:https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview and replace `mat` into `md`.

Comment: you should upgrade the version in your code also but it might break the code in many places

Comment: yeah....it is procrastinating as team regulation since upgrade and re-code need lots of effort...but you are totally right.

Answer (score 0):

Override the properties of .mat-tooltip css class in your style file and adjust the top and left position accordingly.

CSS:

```
::ng-deep .mat-tooltip {
    position: relative;
    left: -30px;
    top:8px;
}
```

Html would be same -

```
  <div>
    <md-input-container class="full-width">
      <input mdInput required placeholder="商品コード" [(ngModel)]="itemCd" mdTooltip="Tooltip!" mdTooltipPosition="above" />
    </md-input-container>
  </div>
```

For demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZTRkej6nlxHayEboIVsi?p=preview